# Replace one instance of "$" (dollar sign) with HTML tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, schema.org

I'm trying to add an HTML tag to a price in my e-com site. So for example: For `$5.00`, I want to add a tag between the `$` and the `5.00` but I can't find the core file to place any code between those 2 separate elements. The file I can access just has a general tag that pulls the full price including currency marker from another file (which I can't find).

I thought I'd try JS to replace the `$5` with `$<span itemprop="price">5</span>` but I have no idea how to write that. My JS skills only go as far as copy and paste.

Can anybody help or suggest a better way to do this? This is for schema markup but google is throwing me an error since the currency marker is inside the price itemprop tag.

Comment: You would need to tell us what shopping cart or ecommerce software you're using. Is it a PHP platform? There will likely be a localised currency string builder method somewhere and it probably does extras like accommodating highlighting of special prices etc.

Comment: Ah sorry. It's a DotNetNuke site so no, not PHP. It's ASP. The actual shopping cart is Catalook.netstore ... I have yet to find someone who is well versed in that lol. Online support for catalook is pretty sparse. :-/

Comment: If you "can't find the core file", how do you expect us to know? I could give you an answer for basic JS/jQuery string replacement, but it sounds like you need to get someone who understands the backend codebase and actually give them access to it. Also you say "ASP", but you really mean "ASP.net", or just .net. ASP is a whole different, pretty archaic, language

Comment: Got it. A string replacement is what I'm looking for ... just didn't use the right words. I apologize for the lack of info. Unfortunately I am a department of 1 and I was tasked with getting this done. Appreciate any advise even if it's just a point in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Basic jQuery to do what you're asking.

But I think you need to re-evaluate how you're going to do this work, and who you're going to get to do it. It shouldn't be done in javascript, and it definitely should be done by a developer who knows what they're doing. You'd also need to modify this for your use-case, make sure it only runs on the parts you want it to, understand how to add jQuery if it isn't already there (I assume it is).

It can be done in plain javascript pretty easily too, I'll write it up if you want.

#### Before I quite understood:

http://jsbin.com/rahayobimo/edit?html,css,js,output

```
$('.price-line').each(function () {
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace('$', '<span>$</span>'))
});
```

#### After I realised it'd require something *slightly* more complex:

http://jsbin.com/xejipeg/1/edit?html,css,js,output

```
$('.price-line').each(function () {
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\$(\d+(\.\d\d)*)/g, '$<span itemprop="price">$1</span>'))
});
```

The second one uses a regex, which checks for dollar-like strings. So something with a dollar, then digits and possibly decimal places. Then it takes that second group (tokenised here as `$1`), wraps it in your tag and sticks an actual dollar sign at the start.

I assume you're only using dollars? If not, change the `$` to `[$£€]` in the first part of the replace function.

Javascript isn't so much of a security concern in this sense. It's just messy and a bit more likely to fail than anything else. Really, you should be taking that raw data *as it comes in* from the back end and formatting it there. Then you definitely know what is a price and what is a currency symbol.

Another problem is that javascript runs *after* the initial page load. So those span tags will be added technically a split second later. Many search engines (which is, I assume, why you're adding this tag) will not see the page based on javascript that's run, only the HTML delivered from the server. This is the bane of people who make web apps that are generated entirely in javascript.

I don't know .net or dotnetnuke, unfortunately. But I know in other languages you would do something similar to this:

- You'd send the variables `currency_symbol` and `price` to a template file
- The template file would take those values, format them and create the correct HTML

For example:

```
<span class="symbol">{{ symbol }}</span><span class="price" itemprop="price">{{ price }}</span>
```

Leaves no room for error, can be cached, better for SEO, lower failure rate, no client dependencies, etc.

Comment: "It shouldn't be done in JS" - Is that because of vulnerability or because it's a workaround?

You're right though, I should find a better way. I was hoping to just find a quick solution. This is what I am trying to achieve:

I want to replace $5 with this:

$<span itemprop="price">5</span>

But without access to the proper file(s), that's why I'm looking for an inline script to add to the page.

Comment: I'll modify my answer with some new code and some explanations of your questions, bear with...!

Comment: Oh no, please bear with ME. You're awesome for trying to help!

Comment: Updated the answer